# module.css files are conflicting even tho they are separated

Tags: css, reactjs

Here's my relevant directory structre

```py
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── Intro.jsx
    │   └── UnderConstruction.jsx
    ├── css
    │   ├── Intro.module.css
    │   └── UnderConstruction.module.css
    ├── images
    │   ├── mascot.png
    │   └── preview.png
    ├── index.js
    └── pages
        └── mainPageLinks
            ├── Blogs.jsx
            ├── Comics.jsx
            └── Projects.jsx
```

My `Intro.jsx`has this

```js
import styles from '../css/Intro.module.css';
```

and my `UnderConstruction.jsx` has

```js
import styles from '../css/UnderConstruction.module.css';
```

My `UnderConstruction.module.css` has

```css
h1{
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
    padding: 0 10%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Weird thing is that this `h1` style is being applied to my `Intro.jsx` file which doesn't even import the `UnderConstruction.module.css` file. I thought `module.css` files are local.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `module.css` files can't really keep the native HTML tags separate so you need to give them some `className`.

So in `*.module.css` file do something like:

```css
.someClassName{
...
}
```

And in the `*.jsx` file do something like

```js
import styles from './path/to/module/css/file';

.
.
.
<h1 className={styles.someClassName}>
    Whatever
</h1>
.
.
.
```